# How to split a long array into smaller arrays, with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array of e-mails (it can be just 1 email, or 100 emails), and I need to send the array with an ajax request (that I know how to do), but I can only send an array that has 10 or less e-mails in it. So if there is an original array of 20 e-mails I will need to split them up into 2 arrays of 10 each. or if there are 15 e-mails in the original array, then 1 array of 10, and another array of 5. I'm using jQuery, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Don't use jquery...use plain javascript

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

var b = a.splice(0,10);

//a is now [11,12,13,14,15];
//b is now [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

You could loop this to get the behavior you want.

```
var a = YOUR_ARRAY;
while(a.length) {
    console.log(a.splice(0,10));
}
```

This would give you 10 elements at a time...if you have say 15 elements, you would get 1-10, the 11-15 as you wanted.

Comment: Note that YOUR_ARRAY will be consumed as well (array are objects...)

Comment: Yeah, i was just putting that because a is non-descriptive, and I already wrote the example using a...it is a completely unnecessary line of code...Although, that makes me think...if using this pattern, you may want to do a deep copy into a working array as to not disrupt you original

Comment: @junvar IDK if that 1-liner worked in 2018 (I seriously doubt it did), but it fails miserably today. You should *never* mutate (i.e. remove elements) an array being iterated over, it throws off the index, i.e. after each removal it should be re-adjusted by the number of elements removed, so it "skips ahead" and doesn't consume the array entirely. [Try it](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-meadow-jmh7r?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js&theme=dark)

Answer (score 168):

```
var size = 10; var arrayOfArrays = [];
for (var i=0; i<bigarray.length; i+=size) {
     arrayOfArrays.push(bigarray.slice(i,i+size));
}
console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

Unlike [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is non-destructive to the original array.

Comment: this solution is better

Comment: @Enrico No, this is right.

Answer (score 55):

You can use lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// → [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 53):

Just loop over the array, splicing it until it's all consumed.

```
var a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
  , chunk

while (a.length > 0) {

  chunk = a.splice(0,3)

  console.log(chunk)

}
```

output

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
[ 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
[ 'g' ]
```

Answer (score 47):

Array.reduce could be inefficient for large arrays, especially with the mod operator.  I think a cleaner (and possibly easier to read) functional solution would be this:

```
const chunkArray = (arr, size) =>
  arr.length > size
    ? [arr.slice(0, size), ...chunkArray(arr.slice(size), size)]
    : [arr];
```

Comment: by far the best and most correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you don't want to destroy the original array, you can use code like this to break up the long array into smaller arrays which you can then iterate over:

```
var longArray = [];   // assume this has 100 or more email addresses in it
var shortArrays = [], i, len;

for (i = 0, len = longArray.length; i < len; i += 10) {
    shortArrays.push(longArray.slice(i, i + 10));
}

// now you can iterate over shortArrays which is an 
// array of arrays where each array has 10 or fewer 
// of the original email addresses in it

for (i = 0, len = shortArrays.length; i < len; i++) {
    // shortArrays[i] is an array of email addresss of 10 or less
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another implementation:

```js
const arr = ["H", "o", "w", " ", "t", "o", " ", "s", "p", "l", "i", "t", " ", "a", " ", "l", "o", "n", "g", " ", "a", "r", "r", "a", "y", " ", "i", "n", "t", "o", " ", "s", "m", "a", "l", "l", "e", "r", " ", "a", "r", "r", "a", "y", "s", ",", " ", "w", "i", "t", "h", " ", "J", "a", "v", "a", "S", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t"];

const size = 3; 
const res = arr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if ( !(i % size)  ) {    // if index is 0 or can be divided by the `size`...
    acc.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));   // ..push a chunk of the original array to the accumulator
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

// => [["H", "o", "w"], [" ", "t", "o"], [" ", "s", "p"], ["l", "i", "t"], [" ", "a", " "], ["l", "o", "n"], ["g", " ", "a"], ["r", "r", "a"], ["y", " ", "i"], ["n", "t", "o"], [" ", "s", "m"], ["a", "l", "l"], ["e", "r", " "], ["a", "r", "r"], ["a", "y", "s"], [",", " ", "w"], ["i", "t", "h"], [" ", "J", "a"], ["v", "a", "S"], ["c", "r", "i"], ["p", "t"]]
```

NB - This does not modify the original array.

Or, if you prefer a functional, 100% immutable (although there's really nothing bad in mutating in place like done above) and self-contained method:

```
function splitBy(size, list) {
  return list.reduce((acc, curr, i, self) => {
    if ( !(i % size)  ) {  
      return [
          ...acc,
          self.slice(i, i + size),
        ];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As a supplement to @jyore's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273794/1778898), and in case you still want to keep the original array:

```
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var splitArray = function (arr, size) {

  var arr2 = arr.slice(0),
      arrays = [];

  while (arr2.length > 0) {
      arrays.push(arr2.splice(0, size));
  }

  return arrays;
}

splitArray(originalArray, 2);
// originalArray is still = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Using ES6 Generators

Late to the party, but [ES6 generators](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-generators.html) opened up another neat way to achieve what is asked for.

```js
/**
 * Returns chunks of size n.
 * @param {Array<any>} array any array
 * @param {number} n size of chunk 
 */
function* chunks(array, n){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i += n) yield array.slice(i, i + n);
}

const result = [...chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10], 3)];
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Make it work for infinite Generators

Using the same idea you can create a generator which can also generate an infinite amount of `n-sized` chunks from values retrieved from another (possibly infinite) generator function. This can be very handy to lazy-generate values once they are required which significantly reduces the required memory or it can even be used to generate a possibly infinite/ unknown number of chunks.

Here an example which uses two generators.

- `nextNaturalNumber()` is an infinite generator which always returns the next natural number. I am using the ES2020 [`bigint`](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_bigints.html) datatype here so there is no restriction (by JavaScript) for the size of the value.
- `chunksFromIterable()` creates `n-sized` chunks from an possibly infinite iterable.

```js
/**
 * Returns chunks of size n for a possibly infinite iterator.
 * n must be >= 1
 * @param {Iterable<any>} iterable any array
 * @param {number} n size of chunk for n >= 1
 */
 function* chunksFromIterable(iterable, n){
  let arr = [];
  let i = n;
  for (const value of iterable) {
    if(i <= 0) {
      // another chunk of size n is filled => return chunk
      yield arr;
      arr = []; // create new empty array
      i = n; 
    };
    arr.push(value);
    i--;
  }
  // in case the iterable is not infinite check if there are still values in the array and return them if necessary
  if(arr.length > 0) yield arr;
}

/**
 * Infinite iterator which always gets the next natural number.
 */
function* nextNaturalNumber(){
  let i = 0n;
  while(true) {
    i += 1n;
    yield i;
  }
}

console.log("Finite iterable:");
// this version can now be used using the for ... of loop
for(const threeNaturalNumbers of chunksFromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10], 3)){
  console.log(threeNaturalNumbers);
}

console.log("Infinite iterable:");
// and it can also be used for this infinite generator
for(const threeNaturalNumbers of chunksFromIterable(nextNaturalNumber(), 3)){
  printBigIntArray(threeNaturalNumbers);
  if(threeNaturalNumbers[0] > 30) break; // end here to avoid an infinite loop
}

// helper function to print array of bigints as this does not seem to be working for snippets
function printBigIntArray(arr){
  console.log(`[${arr.join(", ")}]`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to share my solution as well. It's a little bit more verbose but works as well.

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

var chunksize = 4;


var chunks = [];

data.forEach((item)=>{
  if(!chunks.length || chunks[chunks.length-1].length == chunksize)
  chunks.push([]);

  chunks[chunks.length-1].push(item);
});

console.log(chunks);
```

Output (formatted):

```
[ [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
  [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
  [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15    ] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can start with an empty array and push inside it sections with your desired range from the original array at the same time you are subtracting from your original array until is empty.

```
const originalArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
const splittedArray = [];
  while (originalArr.length > 0) {
    splittedArray.push(originalArr.splice(0,range));  
  }
```

output for range 3

```
splittedArray === [[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9][10,11]]
```

output for range 4

```
splittedArray === [[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,11]]
```

This is also good for a fronted pagination if want.

Comment: Could you please add some description?

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

```
var longArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var size = 2;

var newArray = new Array(Math.ceil(longArray.length / size)).fill("")
    .map(function() { return this.splice(0, size) }, longArray.slice());

// newArray = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]];
```

This doesn't affect the original array as a copy, made using slice, is passed into the 'this' argument of map.

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation, using Array.reduce (I think it’s the only one missing!):

```
const splitArray = (arr, size) =>
{
    if (size === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    return arr.reduce((split, element, index) => {
        index % size === 0 ? split.push([element]) : split[Math.floor(index / size)].push(element);
        return split;
    }, []);
};
```

As many solutions above, this one’s non-destructive. Returning an empty array when the size is 0 is just a convention. If the `if` block is omitted you get an error, which might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

More compact:

```js
const chunk = (xs, size) =>
  xs.map((_, i) =>
    (i % size === 0 ? xs.slice(i, i + size) : null)).filter(Boolean);
    
// Usage:
const sampleArray = new Array(33).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => i);

console.log(chunk(sampleArray, 5));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var newArr=[];

    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i+= size){
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
    }
    return newArr;

}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by adding some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this code . Simple and Effective .

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(array, unit) {
var results = [],
length = Math.ceil(array.length / unit);

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    results.push(array.slice(i * unit, (i + 1) * unit));
}
 return results;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one liner

```js
var segment = (arr, n) => arr.reduce((r,e,i) => i%n ? (r[r.length-1].push(e), r)
                                                    : (r.push([e]), r), []),
        arr = Array.from({length: 31}).map((_,i) => i+1);
console.log(segment(arr,7));
```

Answer (score 1):

as a function

```
var arrayChunk = function (array, chunkSize) {
            var arrayOfArrays = [];

            if (array.length <= chunkSize) {
                arrayOfArrays.push(array);
            } else {
                for (var i=0; i<array.length; i+=chunkSize) {
                    arrayOfArrays.push(array.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
                }
            }
            return arrayOfArrays;
        }
```

to use

```
arrayChunk(originalArray, 10) //10 being the chunk size.
```

Answer (score 1):

using recursion

```
let myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
let size = 4; //Math.sqrt(myArr.length); --> For a n x n matrix
let tempArr = [];
function createMatrix(arr, i) {
    if (arr.length !== 0) {
      if(i % size == 0) {
        tempArr.push(arr.splice(0,size))
      } 
      createMatrix(arr, i - 1)
    }
}
createMatrix(myArr, myArr.length);
console.log(tempArr);
```

Note: The existing array i.e. myArr will be modified.

Answer (score 1):

using prototype we can set directly to array class

```js
Array.prototype.chunk = function(n) {
  if (!this.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return [this.slice(0, n)].concat(this.slice(n).chunk(n));
};
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15].chunk(5));
```

Comment: Can you explain\give source to me how this works?

Comment: @Nandha Frost  ->   we are slicing the array with size n where we are only accessing current scope and creating sub arrays and then we are contacting the subarrays, while we are using CHUNK () as recursion which also a protype function that why we are calling it on THIS scope itself

Answer (score 1):

```
let original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
let size = 5;
let fragments = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(a.length / size))).map((_,index) => a.slice(index * size,(index + 1) * size))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by adding some explanation.

Comment: `ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function if you know the number array (**numGroups**) to be split.

```
function createGroups(arr, numGroups) {
    const perGroup = Math.ceil(arr.length / numGroups);
    return new Array(numGroups)
        .fill('')
        .map((_, i) => arr.slice(i * perGroup, (i + 1) * perGroup));
}
```

Sample Use:

```
createGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3); //arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and numGroups = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that doesn't modify the existing array, try this:

```
let oldArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
let newArray = [];
let size = 3; // Size of chunks you are after
let j = 0; // This helps us keep track of the child arrays

for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  if (i % size === 0) {
    j++
  }
  if(!newArray[j]) newArray[j] = [];
  newArray[j].push(oldArray[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var newArr=[];

    for (var i=0; arr.length>size; i++){
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0,size));
    }
    newArr.push(arr.slice(0));
    return newArr;

}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3);
```

Comment: dont forget to make: newArr=[] a local variable

Comment: Code-only Answers tend to get flagged and then deleted for being Low Quality.  Could you provide some commentary around how this solves the original problem?

Comment: this doesn't work if the chunk size is less than the input array size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve the required functionality

```js
const splitter = (arr, splitBy, cache = []) => {
        const tmp = [...arr]
        while (tmp.length) cache.push(tmp.splice(0, splitBy))
        return cache
}
const split = splitter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21], 10)
console.log(split);
```

Notice, it was an array of length 22 then the **splitter** function splits it into 2 smaller arrays of 10 items and 1 array of 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
let _splitCount = 3;

let b = a.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (index % _splitCount === 0) {
    acc.push([curr]);
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

this is the easy solution i think❤️

Answer (score 0):

You could use map+filter as an alternative to reduce:

```
a.map((x,i,a,chunk=3)=>i%chunk ? null: a.slice(i,i+chunk)).filter(x=>x)
```