# Split array into chunks of N length

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to split an array (which has 10 items) into 4 chunks, which contain a maximum of `n` items.

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
//a function splits it to four arrays.
console.log(b, c, d, e);
```

And it prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
['j', 'h', 'i']
['j']
```

The above assumes `n = 3`, however, the value should be dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: No, I just read `slice` and `splice` docs..

Comment: Duplicate question, see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/1361399

Comment: @Mageek: I was looking for a built-in function. I know I can do it with a loop or multiple `splice`. Should I post my tests result here? :| However, I don't think my work is `dirty`...

Comment: Check this solution [Split Array Into Chunks][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Answer (score 224):

It could be something like that:

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

var arrays = [], size = 3;
    
while (a.length > 0)
  arrays.push(a.splice(0, size));

console.log(arrays);
```

See [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) Array's method.

An alternative method that does not mutate the array, beside create a shallow copy of it before chunk it, could be done by using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and a for…loop:

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

var arrays = [], size = 3;
    
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += size)
   arrays.push(a.slice(i, i + size));

console.log(arrays);
```

While a more functional programming oriented approach, could be:

```js
const chunks = (a, size) =>
    Array.from(
        new Array(Math.ceil(a.length / size)),
        (_, i) => a.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
    );

let a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

console.log(chunks(a, 3));
console.log(chunks(a, 2));
```

See [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and how [new Array(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) works, specifically.

Comment: It's worth noting that this method _mutates_ the old array.

Comment: Can you link to a better method?

Comment: Define "better". This is the simplest way I know to do what was requested. If you don't want to mutate the original array you can a shallow copy of it.

Comment: What is `a` here?

Comment: `a` was part of the OP question. I'll edit my answer to be a running snippet and include the original array,

Answer (score 75):

Maybe this code helps:

```js
var chunk_size = 10;
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];
var groups = arr.map( function(e,i){ 
     return i%chunk_size===0 ? arr.slice(i,i+chunk_size) : null; 
}).filter(function(e){ return e; });
console.log({arr, groups})
```

Comment: I like your solution. I cleaned it up a bit and made it a JS Bin. Thanks! http://jsbin.com/dokivomuzake/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Much better functional solution.

Comment: `const partitionArray = (array, size) =>
  array.map( (e,i) => (i % size === 0)
    ? array.slice(i, i + size)
    : null
  )
  .filter( (e) => e )`

Comment: Perfect solution. +10

Comment: Within the `map` you can simplify it by using `return i%chunk_size===0 && arr.slice(i,i+chunk_size);`

Comment: how to split it into two chunks but include the value from the previous chunk?

Comment: @Buts - [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates through each element of the array.

Comment: This goes through a lot of iterations that aren't necessary.  With the values given it does 17 iterations (34 if you consider `filter`) of which only 2 are used.

Comment: @SandyGifford for liner version you can try this one 
`arr.reduce((r,e,i) => { i%chunk_size===0 ? r.push([e]) : r[r.length-1].push(e); return r; },[])`

Comment: @Mirodil That's slightly better, but you're almost certainly going to get better performance out of letting slice do the second level of iteration for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273717/1496453 - more readable, too.

Comment: @SandyGifford it is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318680/split-array-into-chunks-of-n-length#11318797 solution, and it gives bit more performance if you change `splice`

Comment: `array.map((item, index) => index % chunk_size === 0 ? array.slice(index, index + chunk_size) : null).filter(Boolean)`

is more modern and cleaner