# How to bin data in an array but include the previous value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called targetPercentage.

```
targetPercentage = [0,33,77,132]
```

How do I bin it into chunks of length 2 but include the previous value?
If possible could also make it into a Javascript object array with its respective properties.

Example output :

```
[0,33]
[33,77]
[77,132]
```

Example output by making it into an array of objects :

```
thresholds : [ {from:0,to:33},{from:33,to:77},{from:77,to:132} ]
```

Something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318680/split-array-into-chunks-of-n-length) but inclusive of the previous value.

Comment: `[from:0,to:33]` is invalid syntax, I'm guessing you meant for that to be an object, not an array?

Comment: He called it an example only.

Comment: @CertainPerformance fixed it. Apologies for that.

Comment: Er, it's still invalid - objects need to have both keys and values. I'm guessing you're looking for either `[ {from:0,to:33},{from:33,to:77},{from:77,to:132} ]` or `[ [0,33],[33,77],[77,132] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array from scratch with `Array.from` and access the `i`th element as well as the `i + 1`th element on every iteration to create the objects:

```js
const targetPercentage = [0,33,77,132];
const result = Array.from(
  { length: targetPercentage.length - 1 },
  (_, i) => ({ from: targetPercentage[i], to: targetPercentage[i + 1] })
);
console.log(result);
```

Or if you want an array of arrays instead:

```
(_, i) => ([ targetPercentage[i], targetPercentage[i + 1] ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const targetPercentage = [0, 33, 77, 132]

const thresholds = []
for (let i = 0; i < targetPercentage.length - 1; i++) {
let range = {
  from: targetPercentage[i],
  to: targetPercentage[i + 1]
 }
 thresholds.push(range) 
}
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

array function-slice(initial,count) -slices the given array into 3 chunks of 2 elements each.

temp array will have[0,33],[33,77],[77,132]

```
 var i,j,temparray,chunk = 2;
        result=[];for (i=0,j=targetPercentage.length; i<j-1; i++) {
            temparray = targetPercentage.slice(i,i+chunk);
           result.push({from:temparray[0],to:temparray[1]});
        }
        console.log(result);
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
function binData(array) {
  let result = []

  for (let i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
    result.push({
      from: array[i],
      to: array[i+1]
    })
  }

 return result
}
```