# Loop 'n' elements in groups in each iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have this array:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

**Example**: I want to construct 5 arrays with each pair in it so it becomes,

```
arr1 = [1,2]
arr2 = [2,4]
arr3 = [5,6]
```

This can of course be solved with the modulo operator(%), since those are simply pairs - so it becomes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] % 2 === 0)
    window['arr' + i].push(arr[i], arr[i - 1])
}
```

There are other ways, e.g with nested loops etc.

I'm feeling that this can be solved with a simpler way however, so I'd like to see more suggestions

---

So what's an elegant way to loop every 'n' items in an array, perform some operation on them and then move on to the next 'n' elements.

**Update:**

*The example above deals with 2 elements in a a 10-element array- That's purely random. I'm not looking for a way to deal with pairs in an array -  The question is about how to **loop every N elements in an array**, perform whatever operation on those N elements and move on to the next N elements*

*I'm also not looking to create new arrays - The question has to do with iterating over the original array, only.*

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement. Why are you trying to dynamically create separate variables? I would think that at least you would want to create an array of arrays?

Comment: Dynamically creating the new `arr` variables is just there for the code example - It has nothing to do with the question at hand

Comment: There are good example of splitting arrays, in the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273668/how-to-split-a-long-array-into-smaller-arrays-with-javascript

Comment: what is the logical significance of a pair? There are 10 elements in the array, 5 pairs, and repeats in the pairs, so elements are unused.  Is this purely random?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use plain old `for` loop, like this

```
var N = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += N) {
    // Do your work with array[i], array[i+1]...array[i+N-1]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just increment by `n` in your `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
    console.log(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
```

You can write a function to automate walking through an array by `n` for you:

```
function walk(arr, n, fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += n)
        fn(arr.slice(i, i + n));
}

walk([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2, function (segment) {
    console.log(segment);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm feeling that this can be solved with a simpler way however

I think that `more efficient` would make a better sentiment here than `simpler`. And when it comes to efficiency, the best way to page through data is only when it is actually needed.

The example below is based on [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library, and operator [page](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/page.html):

```
import {pipe, page} from 'iter-ops';

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const i = pipe(arr, page(2)); //=> Iterable<number[]>

// iteration below will trigger the actual paging,
// one page at a time:

for (const a of i) {
    console.log(a); //=> [1, 2], [2, 4], [5, 6]
}
```

P.S. I'm the author if [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops).

Comment: Just a disclaimer that **you wrote** this  library

Comment: @nicholaswmin Disclaimer added ;)