# How to split array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have array in javascript :

```
var category : [{Kode: "AK, BK, CC, CS, DH, GR, KZ, MS, OD, YU "}]
```

and

```
var value : [{value: "376.98, 676.96, 477.23, 1248.89, 573.04, 432.45, 440.92, 397.41, 372.36, 376.59 "}]
```

i want to output :

```
var category : ['AK', 'BK', 'CC', 'CS', 'DH', 'GR', 'KZ', 'MS', 'OD', 'YU']

var value : [376.98, 676.96, 477.23, 1248.89, 573.04, 432.45, 440.92, 397.41, 372.36, 376.59]
```

Please help me, thanks :)

Comment: We don't help you unless you show your efforts.

Comment: You should access the inner property and split by your demiliter like: `category = category.map(x => x.Kcode.split(','));`

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The idea here is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: See here you can find something helpful.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273668/how-to-split-a-long-array-into-smaller-arrays-with-javascript

Comment: You already seem to know you need to use `split()`, so I'm not really sure what more help anyone can offer...?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to try split in javascript:

```
 var cat_result= category[0].Kode.split(",");
 var val_result= value[0].value.split(",");
```

It works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

TRY this `Object.keys() and Object.values()` method . i was mention both are individual  variable

```js
var category = [{
  Kode: "AK, BK, CC, CS, DH, GR, KZ, MS, OD, YU "
}]


var value = [{
  value: "376.98, 676.96, 477.23, 1248.89, 573.04, 432.45, 440.92, 397.41, 372.36, 376.59 "
}]
var res = {}

res[Object.keys(category[0])] = Object.values(category[0])[0].split(',');
res[Object.keys(value[0])] = Object.values(value[0])[0].split(',');

console.log(res)
```

with in single Object

```js
var arr = {
    category: [{
      Kode: "AK, BK, CC, CS, DH, GR, KZ, MS, OD, YU "
    }],
    value: [{
      value: "376.98, 676.96, 477.23, 1248.89, 573.04, 432.45, 440.92, 397.41, 372.36, 376.59 "
    }]
 }

var res = {}
Object.values(arr).forEach(function(a){
res[Object.keys(a[0])] = Object.values(a[0])[0].split(',');
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Category, you can use following code**

```
var category = [{Kode: "AK, BK, CC, CS, DH, GR, KZ, MS, OD, YU "}]; 
var categoryList= category[0].Kode.split(",");
console.log(category[0].Kode.split(","));
```

**For Values, you can use following code:**

```
var value = [{value: "376.98, 676.96, 477.23, 1248.89, 573.04, 432.45, 440.92, 397.41, 372.36, 376.59 "}]; 
var valueList= value[0].value.split(","); 
console.log(valueList)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to done like. Thanks

```js
var category = [{
  Kode: "AK, BK, CC, CS, DH, GR, KZ, MS, OD, YU "
}];

var array = $.map(category[0], function(value, index) {
  return [value];
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet so you can see why it doesn't work. I'd suggest you at least test things before you answer - if you want to avoid downvotes anyway.