# Mapping array to JSX elements inside rows

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Using React I am trying to map an array of elements into a containing HTML element.

However I can not figure out how to map two elements into one HTML element since these elements will have to be closed.

This is an example of what I would like to do. Map two components inside a containing element of className="row" but I can not because the JSX elements have to be closed:

```
const CalendarGrid = (events) => {
  let content = [];
  events.events.map((event, index) =>{

    if (index % 2 != 0) {
        content.push(
          <div className="row">   
          <EventCardRight key={event.id} event={event} align="right"/>
        )
      }if (index % 2 == 0)
      {
          content.push(
            <EventCardLeft key={event.id} event={event} />
            </div className="row">   
          );
      }

  });
  return (
    <div>
        {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [inline logical operators](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) and map through `events` directly as:

```
const CalendarGrid = (events) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {events.events.map((event, index) => 
        <div key={event.id} className="row">
          {index % 2 != 0 ? (
            <EventCardRight key={event.id} event={event} align="right"/>
          ) : (
            <EventCardLeft key={event.id} event={event} />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would split your array to chunks of size 2. See [How to split a long array into smaller arrays, with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273668/how-to-split-a-long-array-into-smaller-arrays-with-javascript), I will use lodash for that:

```
const rows = _.chunk(events.events, 2);
```

now I can simply map every `row` to elements:

```
const content = rows.map((rowEvents, index) => (
   <div key={index} className="row">
      <EventCardRight event={rowEvents[0]} align="right" />
      <EventCardLeft event={rowEvents[1]} />
   </div>
));
```